# Web API 2.1 in Linux or OS X

Tags: asp.net, linux, mono, xamarin, xsp

I'm working on getting Web API 2.1 running on Linux and OS X with Monodevelop in Linux and Xamarin Studio on OS X. I think I have it close but I keep running into this error.

```
Could not load type 'System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HttpRouteExceptionHandler' from assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

I this something that is not in the Mono DLLs? Would it be possible to get this from Windows?

I'd like to be able to do all the development Linux and OS X and run this on a Windows Server.

Comment: maybe you can find System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll in nuget?

Comment: I also have this exact problem. System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll is referenced in the project. Will keep digging.

Comment: Same problem here. I'm running on OS X 10.9.3, using Xamarin Studio 5.0.1.3-0, .NET 4.5, and MVC 4. Everything works fine on Windows 8 with Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web.

Comment: Did you manage to get Web API2 running on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell it is a bug in Mono/Xamari according to their bugzilla: [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=19314), so until they update the aspnetstack. You will keep having this problem.

Comment: For now this is too bad. Looks like vNext is should be available in the future though which is great! https://github.com/aspnet/home.